# Screen Flickering on Ubuntu 16.04 with HP laptop and Intel graphics Card

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, amd-graphics

about a week or two ago my HP laptop screen began flickering incessantly. I run Ubuntu 16.04 and my graphics card is Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset. This is weird because I've been running 16.04 for like two years and now all of a sudden flickering began. I've been on other forums that talk about how doing stuff in the "additional drivers" section of Ubuntu will fix this problem but whenever I go there it says there are no additional drivers available. How do I fix this? Also, whenver I type in lshw -c video I get

[Result of lshw -c video command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBYmm.png)